# How to add a screenshot with form factor set to wide (warning for PWA from DevTools)

Tags: vuejs3, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

How to solve following chrome devtools warning:
Richer PWA Install UI won't be available on desktop. Please add at least one screenshot with "form_factor" set to "wide"

[image]

This is what the manifest.json looks like:

```
  "name": "WKB Progressive Web App",
  "short_name": "WKB PWA",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#01bd7e",
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "icons": [
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/maskable_icon.png",
        "sizes": "1024x1024",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/maskable_icon_x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/maskable_icon_x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/SmallTile.scale-100.png",
        "sizes": "71x71"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/SmallTile.scale-125.png",
        "sizes": "89x89"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/SmallTile.scale-150.png",
        "sizes": "107x107"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/SmallTile.scale-200.png",
        "sizes": "142x142"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/SmallTile.scale-400.png",
        "sizes": "284x284"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png",
        "sizes": "150x150"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square150x150Logo.scale-125.png",
        "sizes": "188x188"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square150x150Logo.scale-150.png",
        "sizes": "225x225"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png",
        "sizes": "300x300"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square150x150Logo.scale-400.png",
        "sizes": "600x600"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png",
        "sizes": "310x150"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Wide310x150Logo.scale-125.png",
        "sizes": "388x188"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Wide310x150Logo.scale-150.png",
        "sizes": "465x225"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png",
        "sizes": "620x300"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Wide310x150Logo.scale-400.png",
        "sizes": "1240x600"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/LargeTile.scale-100.png",
        "sizes": "310x310"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/LargeTile.scale-125.png",
        "sizes": "388x388"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/LargeTile.scale-150.png",
        "sizes": "465x465"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/LargeTile.scale-200.png",
        "sizes": "620x620"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/LargeTile.scale-400.png",
        "sizes": "1240x1240"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png",
        "sizes": "44x44"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.scale-125.png",
        "sizes": "55x55"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.scale-150.png",
        "sizes": "66x66"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png",
        "sizes": "88x88"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.scale-400.png",
        "sizes": "176x176"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/StoreLogo.scale-100.png",
        "sizes": "50x50"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/StoreLogo.scale-125.png",
        "sizes": "63x63"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/StoreLogo.scale-150.png",
        "sizes": "75x75"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/StoreLogo.scale-200.png",
        "sizes": "100x100"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/StoreLogo.scale-400.png",
        "sizes": "200x200"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/SplashScreen.scale-100.png",
        "sizes": "620x300"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/SplashScreen.scale-125.png",
        "sizes": "775x375"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/SplashScreen.scale-150.png",
        "sizes": "930x450"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/SplashScreen.scale-200.png",
        "sizes": "1240x600"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/SplashScreen.scale-400.png",
        "sizes": "2480x1200"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-16.png",
        "sizes": "16x16"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-20.png",
        "sizes": "20x20"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24.png",
        "sizes": "24x24"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-30.png",
        "sizes": "30x30"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-32.png",
        "sizes": "32x32"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-36.png",
        "sizes": "36x36"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-40.png",
        "sizes": "40x40"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-44.png",
        "sizes": "44x44"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-60.png",
        "sizes": "60x60"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-64.png",
        "sizes": "64x64"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-80.png",
        "sizes": "80x80"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-16.png",
        "sizes": "16x16"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-20.png",
        "sizes": "20x20"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-24.png",
        "sizes": "24x24"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-30.png",
        "sizes": "30x30"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-32.png",
        "sizes": "32x32"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-36.png",
        "sizes": "36x36"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-40.png",
        "sizes": "40x40"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-44.png",
        "sizes": "44x44"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-60.png",
        "sizes": "60x60"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-64.png",
        "sizes": "64x64"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-80.png",
        "sizes": "80x80"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-16.png",
        "sizes": "16x16"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-20.png",
        "sizes": "20x20"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-24.png",
        "sizes": "24x24"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-30.png",
        "sizes": "30x30"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-32.png",
        "sizes": "32x32"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-36.png",
        "sizes": "36x36"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-40.png",
        "sizes": "40x40"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-44.png",
        "sizes": "44x44"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-60.png",
        "sizes": "60x60"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-64.png",
        "sizes": "64x64"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-80.png",
        "sizes": "80x80"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/windows11/Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/android/android-launchericon-512-512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/android/android-launchericon-192-192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/android/android-launchericon-144-144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/android/android-launchericon-96-96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/android/android-launchericon-72-72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/android/android-launchericon-48-48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/16.png",
        "sizes": "16x16"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/20.png",
        "sizes": "20x20"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/29.png",
        "sizes": "29x29"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/32.png",
        "sizes": "32x32"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/40.png",
        "sizes": "40x40"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/50.png",
        "sizes": "50x50"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/57.png",
        "sizes": "57x57"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/58.png",
        "sizes": "58x58"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/60.png",
        "sizes": "60x60"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/64.png",
        "sizes": "64x64"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/76.png",
        "sizes": "76x76"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/80.png",
        "sizes": "80x80"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/87.png",
        "sizes": "87x87"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/100.png",
        "sizes": "100x100"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/114.png",
        "sizes": "114x114"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/120.png",
        "sizes": "120x120"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/128.png",
        "sizes": "128x128"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/152.png",
        "sizes": "152x152"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/167.png",
        "sizes": "167x167"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/180.png",
        "sizes": "180x180"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512"
      },
      {
        "src": "/img/icons/ios/1024.png",
        "sizes": "1024x1024"
      }
    ]
}
```

This is a Vue 3 app.

I don't know what the message is about, but I'd like to understand what it is about and get rid of it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what it says. In order for the browsers to offer a better/ 'Richer' UI experience when the PWA is being installed, you'll need to add screenshots (and a description) to your manifest file with different form_factors options (wide and unset).
The entry would be something similar to this

```
"screenshots": [    
   {

     "src": "source/image1.gif",
      "sizes": "640x320",
      "type": "image/gif",
      "form_factor": "wide",
      "label": "Application"
    }
 ]
```

You can find a very good example [here](https://web.dev/patterns/web-apps/richer-install-ui/)